# What is the point of preceding page title with a tag name?

Tags: discussion, tags

When I am viewing a question, the browser page title has the form:

Tag - Title

where "Title" is the question's title field, and "Tag", it seems, is the first tag (alphabetically) assigned to the question.

Why is this done?  I don't see any value to it.  Since there is no way to order tags manually (seem to be arrange alphabetically), the one tag chosen may not be significantly relevant to the question's essence.  So why show one at all?

It makes it more difficult to locate a browser window or tab when some irrelevant word is dominating the tiny spaced allowed for a title...

Comment: Hunch: this may be related to SEO, or was related to SEO at some earlier time.

Comment: The ordering of tags in a question is by number of existing uses of the tag.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's mainly for Search Engine Optimization. See the answers on here:

- [Why is the first tag sometimes in the <title> tag of some questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions)
- [Does the order of keywords matter in a page title?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title)
- [Why is the least important tag in the title of this StackExchange page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72377/why-is-the-least-important-tag-in-the-title-of-this-stackexchange-page)

As for which tag, it's generally the -

- Most popular tag
- not already included in the title text
- by order which it appears in the tag (if two tags have the same rank)
- Sometimes two tags for some odd reason.

It is not by alphabetic order. Or it shouldn't be.

Comment: Well, I was unable to explicitly set the order of tags... The order gets rearranged for me, and the order just happened to be alphabetical (just a coincidence?  Dunno)